# How to check any pipe separated data is empty

Tags: shell, unix, awk, text-processing

I am trying to implement this but not getting

I have below data in file

```
A|B|C|D
AX | GH | H
FG |HJJK | 
  | GHJ | 
AG |
```

I need to check like line should have data in between pipe

**Expected output**

```
Line 1 : as proper data 
Line 2 : as proper data 
Line 3 : No proper data 
Line 4 : No proper data 
Line 5 : No proper data
```

I am trying to frame code for it

```
IFS=''
    while -r data
    do 
       var1=`echo "$data" | awk -F'|' '{print $1}'
       var2=`echo "$data" | awk -F'|' '{print $2}'
       var3=`echo "$data" | awk -F'|' '{print $3}'
       if [ ! -z $var1  ]  && [! -z $var2] && [! -z $var3]
       then
            echo "as poper data"
       else
            echo "No proper data"
       fi  
    done < file.txt
```

How to write a generic code it should work for any file of data if it as pipe separated data .

Draw back of my code and if their are 3 columns I need to create 3 var variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
A|B|C|D
AX | GH | H
FG |HJJK | 
  | GHJ | 
AG |
```

———————————————————————

```
{m,g}awk '$-_=sprintf("Line %5.f : %s proper data",
                       NR, (!_)< NF ? "No" : "as")' \
                       FS='(^|[|])[ \t]*[|]|[|][ \t]*$'
```

———————————————————————

```
Line     1 : as proper data
Line     2 : as proper data
Line     3 : No proper data
Line     4 : No proper data
Line     5 : No proper data
```

————————————————————

**VERSION WITH EXIT CODE**

```
{m,g}awk '!_<NF { exit !_ } !_' FS='(^|[|])[ \t]*[|]|[|][ \t]*$'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
A|B|C|D
AX | GH | H
```

**EXIT CODE**

```
echo "$?"

1
```

Comment: No able to understand your code. And what if need to exit 
the code if any one is having no data how to apply this exit 1

Comment: @kiric8494 : any parts of the code you like me to elaborate upon ? i'm not using any  syntax specific to a single variant of awk.

Answer (score 1):

An easier to understand `awk`:

```bash
awk -F '|' '
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i)
      if ($i ~ /^[[:blank:]]*$/) {
         print "Line", NR, ": No proper data"
         next
      }
   print "Line", NR, ": as proper data"
}' file

Line 1 : as proper data
Line 2 : as proper data
Line 3 : No proper data
Line 4 : No proper data
Line 5 : No proper data
```

Answer (score 0):

Just grep for a pipe in front of the line, pipe on the end of line, or pipe with nothing in between.

```
if grep -q '^[[:blank:]]*|\||[[:blank:]]*$\||[[:blank:]]*|' file.txt; then
      echo "as poper data"
else
      echo "No proper data"
fi
```

Comment: The code does not work for me. giving me output : `as proper data`